# phone gap is not showing simulator on IOS 6

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am new to phone gap i have created app for ios by following the steps given on

[phonegap IOS](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS)

when i run the application by choosing target Cordova it build succeeded but it is not showing simulator

when i choose target helloworld it give me two errors

`"Apple Mach-O Linker error"`

I am using,
 **xcode 4.5,
 MAC OS 10.8,
 phonegap 2.2.0**

Comment: By changing phonegap version to old one 2.1.0 Issue solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing phonegap version to old one 2.1.0 Issue solved